# How to have only One index col for my dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with the following dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xzvw-z_glMcOYxJPJ4SckuKrVOulUuzO/view?usp=sharing

Here is a preview of my problem:
[image]

If you observe I am now having 3 index-like cols. I want to get rid of that and only have 1. Normally it would not have been a problem, but I am trying to deploy my model using flask and I am getting an error saying that `ValueError: X has 25 features, but MultinomialNB is expecting 28 features as input.` I want to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

If df is your DataFrame:

```
df = df.drop('ID', axis=1)
```

This will remove the ID column